# Trying to export data to excel, works but the code is clunky-repeated per sheet

Tags: r, excel, r-markdown, xlsx

I am exporting some code to excel, and trying to do it to 1 workbook over 3 sheets. However to do this I have repeated each command thrice, this can't be a good way to do it? Perhaps someone can tell me where I'm going wrong?

```
library(r2excel)
#> Loading required package: xlsx

 sample_prime1 <- 1:4
 sample_prime2 <- 10:14
 sample_prime3 <- 22:26
# Create an Excel workbook. 
filename <- "validitycheck.xlsx" #The name of the file that will be saved
wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx") #Creating an excel workbook

# Create a sheet in that workbook to contain the data table
sheet1 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "prime1")
sheet2 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "prime2")
sheet3 <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = "prime3")
 

# Add table : add a data frame for sheet 1
xlsx.addHeader(wb, sheet1, value="Validty for prime 1")
xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet1, 1)
xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet1, sample_prime1,
               fontColor="darkblue", fontSize=14,
              rowFill=c("white", "lightblue"),
              startCol=2, 
              row.names=FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE)

# Add table : add a data frame for sheet 2
xlsx.addHeader(wb, sheet2, value="Validty for prime 2")
xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet2, 1)
xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet2, sample_prime2,
               fontColor="darkblue", fontSize=14,
              rowFill=c("white", "lightblue"),
              startCol=2, 
              row.names=FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE)


# Add table : add a data frame for sheet 3
xlsx.addHeader(wb, sheet3, value="Validty for prime 3")
xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet3, 1)
xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet3, sample_prime3,
               fontColor="darkblue", fontSize=14,
              rowFill=c("white", "lightblue"),
              startCol=2, 
              row.names=FALSE, 
              col.names = FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea of **@DavidMas** is great (kudos and many thanks for teaching this to us). You can improve the function and generalize it to `n` data working with a list to store the data and a vector for the names. Then you can use a loop to print the data. Here the code:

```
library(r2excel)
#Data
sample_prime1 <- 1:4
sample_prime2 <- 10:14
sample_prime3 <- 22:26
#Store in a list
List <- list(sample_prime1,sample_prime2,sample_prime3)
#Function
myfun <- function(wb,name,df) {
  # Create object
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = name)
  # Add headers
  xlsx.addHeader(wb, sheet, value=paste0('Validty for prime ',name))
  xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet, 1)
  xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet, data.frame(df),
                fontColor="darkblue", fontSize=14,
                rowFill=c("white", "lightblue"),
                startCol=2, 
                row.names=FALSE, 
                col.names = FALSE)
}
#Create workbook
filename <- "validitycheck.xlsx" 
wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")
#Loop
#Vector for names
vnames <- paste0('prime',1:length(List))
#Code
for(i in 1:length(List))
{
  myfun(wb,vnames[i],List[i])
}
```

Comment: @Gabriella It is always a pleasure, Dr Gabriella. If you have any trouble with coding let me know. You are at Oxford, I am at Edinburgh!

Comment: I am not a Dr yet! give it a few more years! Hello from Oxford to Edinburgh!!! Thank you, I think you will regret the offer!!!

Comment: @Gabriella I never regret about the offers I do otherwise all the knowledge I have would not be useful. Hope to hear from you soon!!! Keep in touch :)

Comment: @Gabriella Any time you need some help you can enable a chat I am always ready to help others with programming knowledge! You can enable chat with this https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187426/how-do-i-chat-with-another-user-on-stackoverflow

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you could make a function and call it 3 times? I don't have the package so I can't test but something like this might work.

```
addSheet <- function(wb,sheetName,value,data) {
  # Create a sheet in that workbook to contain the data table
  sheet <- createSheet(wb, sheetName = sheetName)
  
  
  # Add table : add a data frame for sheet 1
  xlsx.addHeader(wb, sheet, value=value)
  xlsx.addLineBreak(sheet, 1)
  xlsx.addTable(wb, sheet, data,
                fontColor="darkblue", fontSize=14,
                rowFill=c("white", "lightblue"),
                startCol=2, 
                row.names=FALSE, 
                col.names = FALSE)
}
```

And then you could run

```
filename <- "validitycheck.xlsx" 
wb <- createWorkbook(type="xlsx")

addSheet(wb,"prime1","Validty for prime 1",sample_prime1)
addSheet(wb,"prime2","Validty for prime 2",sample_prime2)
addSheet(wb,"prime3","Validty for prime 3",sample_prime3)
```